# How are Shoya and Maria related?

Tags: koe-no-katachi

In *A Silent Voice*, Shoya lives with his mom and a little girl named Maria. He refers to Maria as his little sister, but the two have different skin colors.

How are Shoya and Maria related?

[image: Shoya and Maria]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It explain pretty well in manga and anime. She's not his sister, but she's his niece. Her mother is Shoya's sister and her father is a Brazilian. [Maria's MAL page](https://myanimelist.net/character/97943/Maria_Ishida) also mentioned

> Ishida's young niece who lives with Ishida and his family. Maria is half-Japanese from her mother's side and half-Brazilian from her father's side.

This is her father

[image: Maria's father]